# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x800000 cmp=com.android.systemui/.recents.RecentsActivity

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to open recent apps but I have a permission problem.

This feature works on Android 4, but seemingly from 6/7 is displaying the following error:

java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x800000 cmp=com.android.systemui/.recents.RecentsActivity }

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.component = ComponentName("com.android.systemui", "com.android.systemui.recents.RecentsActivity")
if (null != intent.resolveActivityInfo(context.packageManager, 0)) {
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: Most likely, that activity is no longer exported.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its because new permissions system in android 6

> Every Android app runs in a limited-access sandbox. If an app needs to
>   use resources or information outside of its own sandbox, the app has
>   to request the appropriate permission. You declare that your app needs
>   a permission by listing the permission in the app manifest and then
>   requesting that the user approve each permission at runtime (on
>   Android 6.0 and higher).
>
> If your app needs a dangerous permission, you must check whether you
>   have that permission every time you perform an operation that requires
>   that permission. Beginning with Android 6.0 (API level 23), users can
>   revoke permissions from any app at any time, even if the app targets a
>   lower API level. So even if the app used the camera yesterday, it
>   can't assume it still has that permission today

check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) for more informations